# How to set time ago in android

Tags: android, datetime

I am getting my `datetime` from server as a `string`. I am trying to set the time to time ago kind of thing. Like `2 minutes ago`, `12 hours ago` etc.

So i delved into googling and ended up with a class to take care of that which was referenced by alot of other developers.

Problem is, i am getting really weird time ago's here.

**For example:** Date string of `2016-03-24 13:08:20`  ends up as `about 11 hours ago` which is not true.

When i try the time for right now/current i get time ago as `15 hours ago`.

I really dont know what is going wrong. Any thoughts?

TimeAgo.class:

```js
public class TimeAgo {

    protected Context context;

    public TimeAgo(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String timeAgo(Date date) {
        return timeAgo(date.getTime());
    }

    public String timeAgo(long millis) {
        long diff = new Date().getTime() - millis;

        Resources r = context.getResources();

        String prefix = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_prefix);
        String suffix = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_suffix);

        double seconds = Math.abs(diff) / 1000;
        double minutes = seconds / 60;
        double hours = minutes / 60;
        double days = hours / 24;
        double years = days / 365;

        String words;

        if (seconds < 45) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_seconds, Math.round(seconds));
        } else if (seconds < 90) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_minute, 1);
        } else if (minutes < 45) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_minutes, Math.round(minutes));
        } else if (minutes < 90) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_hour, 1);
        } else if (hours < 24) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_hours, Math.round(hours));
        } else if (hours < 42) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_day, 1);
        } else if (days < 30) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_days, Math.round(days));
        } else if (days < 45) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_month, 1);
        } else if (days < 365) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_months, Math.round(days / 30));
        } else if (years < 1.5) {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_year, 1);
        } else {
            words = r.getString(R.string.time_ago_years, Math.round(years));
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (prefix != null && prefix.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(prefix).append(" ");
        }

        sb.append(words);

        if (suffix != null && suffix.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(" ").append(suffix);
        }

        return sb.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

How i use it:

```js
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
// example of time format 2016-03-24 13:08:20
                                Date date = formatter.parse(jObject.getString("time_stamp")); // You will need try/catch around this
                                long millis = date.getTime();
                                TimeAgo timeAgo = new TimeAgo(getApplicationContext());

 //where i set the time
rm.settime_stamp(String.valueOf(timeAgo.timeAgo(millis)));
```

Comment: It would much better to store the date as a long value then you could use the DateUtils class to get the relative time span.

Comment: Probably a timezone problem of some kind. What are the actual millis values that end up getting compared? (`new Date().getTime()` and `millis`?)

Comment: Your 'new Date().getTime()' is probably different from server's timezone. You will have to use server's time zone at all times, which means manipulating  new Date().getTime() to match your server's timezone before comparing the two values.

Comment: @Sevle But the server returns the time correctly when i compare with my own time.

Comment: If thats the case, I don't have an idea why it doesnt work. Try swapping new Date().getTime() with Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).getTimeInMillis() just to satisfy my stubbornness!

Comment: @Sevle nope, that hasn't fixed the issue yet.

Comment: @MattGibson for my time 2016-03-24 17:24:29 i get millis value as 1458840269000

Comment: But what is the value (in milliseconds) returned from `new Date().getTime()`? It'll be helpful to see both (from the same run) to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Okay let's start afresh. I have hardcoded datetime string as `2016-3-24 18:20:20`. The value of new `Date().getTime()` is `1458843620000` while `millis` is  `1458843620000`. Ideas?

Comment: You can't start afresh, because there is obviously a  difference between your millis and Date.getTime(). In other words, hardcoding 1458843620000 returns 'seconds 0 ago'!

Comment: Yes i have observed that too. Not a good idea.

Comment: Both Sevle and @Matt Gibson are right. Server's timezone was the problem. I attached time from my device with my requests and that seems to work fine.